# JMeter - Requests not getting grouped within controllers in graph output

Tags: jmeter

In my test plan I have a series of steps like Login, HomePage, DoSearch, DoTask, Logout and each has a number of HTTP requests. I have tried using Simple Controllers, Transaction Controllers, keeping transaction controllers within simple controllers, and vice versa but am unable to see the timings at a step level in any graph. It at the most shows me the timings for Login, but other requests are not grouped on either controllers. Tried checking "Generate Parent Sample" and "Include duration..." but no luck.

Can someone let me know what needs to be done here?

Comment: what do you want? to test each sampler execution time or what? I can't tell what are you asking

Comment: See the timings at a step or transaction level (Login, ViewDashboard, ChangeFilters, Logout etc.) in any JMeter graph.

Comment: Ok, is `View results in a table` listener not good enough for you? take a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/11450100/169277 , is that what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a Listener. Each listener provides different information. I usually just use aggregate report.